# Append element after another element using lxml

Tags: python, html, append, lxml

I have the following HTML markup

```
<div id="contents">
    <div id="content_nav">
        something goes here
    </div>
    <p>
        some contents
    </p>   
</div>
```

To fix some CSS issue, I want to append a div tag `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the `content_nav` div like this

```
<div id="contents">
    <div id="content_nav">
        something goes here
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <p>
        some contents
    </p>   
</div>
```

I am doing it this way:

```
import lxml.etree

tree = lxml.etree.fromString(inputString, parser=lxml.etree.HTMLParser())

contentnav = tree.find(".//div[@id='content_nav']")
contentnav.append(lxml.etree.XML("<div style='clear: both'></div>"))
```

But that doesn't append the new `div` right after `content_nav` div but inside.

```
<div id="content_nav">
    something goes here
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to add a `div` in the middle of `content_nav` div and some `p` like that inside `contents`?

Thanks

Comment: CSS only solution: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Instead of appending to `contentnav`, go up to the parent (`contentdiv`) and `insert` the new `div` at a particular index. To find that index, use `contentdiv.index(contentnav)`, which gives the index of `contentnav` within `contentdiv`. Adding one to that gives the desired index.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content = '''\
<div id="contents">
    <div id="content_nav">
        something goes here
    </div>
    <p>
        some contents
    </p>   
</div>
'''
tree = ET.fromstring(content, parser=ET.HTMLParser())
contentnav = tree.find(".//div[@id='content_nav']")
contentdiv = contentnav.getparent()
contentdiv.insert(contentdiv.index(contentnav)+1,
                  ET.XML("<div style='clear: both'></div>"))
print(ET.tostring(tree))
```

yields

```
<html><body><div id="contents">
    <div id="content_nav">
        something goes here
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"/><p>
        some contents
    </p>   
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing after asking the question. :)

Answer (score 17):

**Use `addprevious` and `addnext` for prepending and appending siblings.**

An lxml.etree `_Element` has two methods: [`addprevious`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#addprevious) and [`addnext`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#addnext) for doing exactly what you want.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content='''\
<div id="contents">
    <div id="content_nav">
        something goes here
    </div>
    <p>
        some contents
    </p>   
</div>
'''
tree = ET.fromstring(content, parser=ET.HTMLParser())
contentnav = tree.find(".//div[@id='content_nav']")
contentnav.addnext(ET.XML("<div style='clear: both'></div>"))
print(ET.tostring(tree))
```

Output:

```
<html><body><div id="contents">
    <div id="content_nav">
        something goes here
    </div><div style="clear: both"/>
    <p>
        some contents
    </p>   
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Should probably be ET.HTML in this case

Answer (score 2):

I believe that a generic function addressing the question *"insert an element after another element"* might be useful, even if it's just a reformulation of the accepted answer:

```
def insert_after(element, new_element):
    parent = element.getparent()
    parent.insert(parent.index(element)+1, new_element)
```

which allows to insert a `new_element` after an existing `element` with just

```
insert_after(element, new_element)
```

Comment: All that you've done is re-implement `element.appendnext()`.

Comment: @Shrewmouse I guess you mean `element.addnext()`. I don't know when it was added to the API but now it is definitively the best solution.