# How to insert a HTML element in a tree of lxml.html

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

*I am using python 3.3 and lxml 3.2.0*

Problem:
I have a web page in a variable `webpageString = "<html><head></head><body>webpage content</body></html>"`
And I want to insert a css link tag between the two header tags, so that I get 
`webpageString = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head><body>webpage content</body></html>"`

I have written the following code:

```
def addCssCode(self):
    tree = html.fromstring(self.article)
    headTag = tree.xpath("//head")
    #htmlTag = tree.getroot()

    if headTag is None:
        pass    #insert the head tag first

    cssLinkString = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='"+ self.cssLocation+"'>"
    headTag[0].insert(1, html.HtmlElement(cssLinkString))
    print(cssLinkString)
    self.article = html.tostring(tree).decode("utf-8")
```

Which results in insertion of-

```
    <HtmlElement>&lt; link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='cssCode.css' &gt;</HtmlElement>
```

I also tried solution in the following page to an identical problem, but it also didn't work.
[python lxml append element after another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474972/python-lxml-append-element-after-another-element)

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.insert`/`.append` method.

```
import lxml.html

def add_css_code(webpageString, linkString):
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(webpageString)
    link = lxml.html.fromstring(linkString).find('.//link')
    head = root.find('.//head')
    title = head.find('title')
    if title == None:
        where = 0
    else:
        where = head.index(title) + 1
    head.insert(where, link)
    return lxml.html.tostring(root)

webpageString1 = "<html><head><title>test</title></head><body>webpage content</body></html>"
webpageString2 = "<html><head></head><body>webpage content</body></html>"
linkString = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>"

print(add_css_code(webpageString1, linkString))
print(add_css_code(webpageString2, linkString))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but it has nothing to with append() method. I have to use insert() because I need to insert the link tag at particular position i.e. after the title tag.